# How to add string text to orElse and .map

Tags: java, android, java-8, option-type

In the below code, I would like to add a log statement to both of .map and .orElse to indicate whether or not the value is true/false. In other words, in .map i would like to add 
    "........true"

inside orElse i would to add
    "........false"

How can I modify the belwo code to include both of the aforementioned Strings.

**code**:

```
return OptionalsUtils.toOptional(this.getBuiltMovieRoomPersistentDatabase())
            .map(builderObj -> builderObj.isOpen())
            .orElse(false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly do that using [`Optional.orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)) which expects  a `Supplier` as:

```
return OptionalsUtils.toOptional(this.getBuiltMovieRoomPersistentDatabase())
        .map(builderObj -> {
            System.out.println("Its true here.");
            return builderObj.isOpen();
        })
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            System.out.println("Its false here");
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: The use of `Supplier` is a smart move. Unfortunately, there is nothing like `Optional:peek` similar to [tag:java-streams].

Comment: @Nikolas I honestly dont know what to do with that if it existed though

Comment: @Nikolas I haven't ever yet faced a situation where debugging with Optional might be required to that extent of `peek`ing within in while the operations.